# How to show a React Native Component inside an iOS Native UI Module?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I'm working with an iOS framework that generates some default callout UI for me [(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmir3.png), lets name it `CalloutView`. Now this `CalloutView` can also accept a custom `UIView`, that will be shown as a child view. It looks something like this -

```
@interface CalloutView: UIView {
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subTitle;
    UIView *customView;

    // ... other properties
}
```

I can create a Native UI Module which will have a one to one mapping with most of the properties.

```
@interface CalloutViewManager: RCTViewManager {
    -(UIView *)view {
       return [[CalloutView alloc] init];
    }

    RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(title, NSString);
    RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(subtitle, NSString);
    // ... other properties
}
```

Which will be used as ->

```
<CalloutView title="Hello" subtitle="How are you" />
```

**My question is, how can I pass in the customView property?**

Maybe it could look something like this on the React side ->

```
   <CalloutView title="Hello" subtitle="How are you">
         <View style={styles.container}>
             <TextView style={styles.customText}> Hello World! </TextView>
         </View>
   </CalloutView>
```

**But how will the `CalloutViewManager` receive the child view?**

Another approach could be to pass in the view as a prop, but again I'm not sure how the iOS side would convert the json into a UIView.